# Is there a ? conditional test in Javascript like in C#?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

```
var isChecked = $('#htmlEdit').is(":checked");
```

But I don't really need the variable isChecked and what I want to do is to assign a value to a variable called "action" so that if the test on the right above is true then

```
var action = "Editing HTML"
```

if not then

```
var action = "Editing"
```

Is there a clean way to do this without just using an if-else?

Comment: Did you try the C# conditional syntax in JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Javascript has a [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). You should be able to write:

```
var action = $('#htmlEdit').is(":checked") ? "Editing HTML" : "Editing";
```

(Did you try this before asking the question?)

Answer (score 7):

Yes there is:

```
var action = $('#htmlEdit').is(":checked") ? "Editing HTML" : "Editing";
```

[Conditional operator on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: Thanks so much. I didn't realize I could do the same as C#.

Comment: Glad it helped. I have added a link for documentation. You could also check the list of [Expressions and Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators).

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = someCondition == true ? "state 1" : "state 2";

// the first operand must evaluate to a boolean
var result = someCondition ? "state 1" : "state 2"; // shortened
var result = a == b ? "state 1" : "state 2"; // arbitrary condition
```

This is the [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/be21c7hw%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) and behaves the same in JavaScript as most/all c-style languages.

Answer (score 1):

`var action = isChecked ? "Editing HTML" : "Editing";`

Comment: OP says that he doesn't really need the var `isChecked`.

Answer (score 0):

`?` is also called as `ternary operator`.

This is more of a language construct, rather than a Framework stuff.

`C#` is a `language` and `Jquery` is a `framework` build on `Javascript` (a language).

And `Javascript` language and most of the languages (`C, C++, C#, Java, Javascript`) support this operator.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use conditional operator:

```
var variableToBeAssigned = conditiontoBechecked ? valueTobeAssignedONSucessOfCondition : valueToBeassignedONFailureOfCondition;
```

In your case, you can just use:

```
var action = $('#htmlEdit').is(':checked') ? 'Editing HTML' : 'Editing';
```